# How to have IntelliJ ignoring a subset of gradle sourceSets?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I work on a compiler written in Java, compiling class files generated by JDK 7 to 11 to another format. To test the compiler, among other things, I have gradle compiling the compiler itself using JDK 7 to 11, and use the output class file as input for the test.

To do that, I set up multiple source sets:

```
compilerJava11 {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main']
        }
    }
compilerJava10 {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main']
        }
    }
...
```

Then I set the compiler for each sourceSet:

```
tasks.named(sourceSets.compilerJava11.compileJavaTaskName).get().configure {
    def jdkDir = 'third_party/openjdk/jdk-11/'
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.jvmArgs = []
    if (OperatingSystem.current().isLinux()) {
        options.forkOptions.javaHome = file(jdkDir + 'Linux')
    } else if (OperatingSystem.current().isMacOsX()) {
        options.forkOptions.javaHome = file(jdkDir + 'Mac')
    } else {
        options.forkOptions.javaHome = file(jdkDir + 'Windows')
    }
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
...
```

And Gradle generates me correctly the class files for the compiler through different JDKs, that I can use correctly as input for the test.

Now my problem is that I work in IntelliJ, and the 'src/main' srcDir is used in multiple sourceSets. IntelliJ gets confused with the contents of the main folder, telling me that multiple copies exist (main.pathToFile, compilerJava10.pathToFile, compilerJava11.pathToFile, etc.), and part of the tools are confused and do not work correctly.

To solve the problem, I went to Project Structure >> Modules and removed all the compilerJava11, compilerJava10, ... modules, keeping only the main module and non related modules. Now I still have the class files output by Gradle through the removed sourceSet and IntelliJ behaves correctly. I need to run gradle outside of IntelliJ to regenerate the class files produced by the different JDKs, but that's ok. So, all good.

Now each time I sync with gradle, I need to remove manually the modules again. This is very annoying.

I would like to specify something in IntelliJ or in the gradle build file so that IntelliJ does not import the gradle sourceSet compilerJava10, compilerJava11, etc. but still import the other sourceSets (main, the other test sourceSet, etc.) as modules.

What can I specify and where so IntelliJ does not import a subset of the available sourceSets as modules?

Could I do something such as:

```
compilerJava11 {
        ideaImport = false
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main']
        }
    }
```

So that idea does not import the compilerJava11 sourceSet.

Alternatively, if you could provide me a way to compile the same sourceSet (in my case main) with different Java compilers and keep the different outputs, that would also work for me.

Thanks

**Solution:**

In the end I stopped duplicating the source sets and created instead separate JavaCompile task to get the compiled class files I wanted. An example would be:

```
task compileMainWithJava11 (type: JavaCompile) {
    def jdkDir = 'third_party/openjdk/jdk-11/'
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.jvmArgs = []
    if (OperatingSystem.current().isLinux()) {
        options.forkOptions.javaHome = file(jdkDir + 'Linux')
    } else if (OperatingSystem.current().isMacOsX()) {
        options.forkOptions.javaHome = file(jdkDir + 'Mac')
    } else {
        options.forkOptions.javaHome = file(jdkDir + 'Windows')
    }
    source = sourceSets.main.allSource
    destinationDir = file(java11ClassFiles)
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
}
```

Then I can access the resulting files in `file(java11ClassFiles)`.
Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: A multi project setup - one project for each "compiler version" - is not an option? You could move the common code base into a common code project. 

Building this with one command is really easy. 

Read https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html if you aren't familiar with multi project setup.

Comment: This should work with Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Create separate module per source set** and Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner | **Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle** options enabled. have you tried it? Does it help?

Comment: I tried Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle but then it slows down the rest of the development process (Gradle is slower than when IntelliJ does it).

I will look into the multi-project setup.